# element-wise averages of two (or more) nested lists of matrices

Tags: r, list, matrix, nested, elementwise-operations

I have two lists `A_1` and `A_2`, each contains two matrices.

```
A_1 <- list(a=matrix(1:8, 2), b=matrix(2:9, 2))

A_2 <- list(a=matrix(10:17, 2), b=matrix(5:12, 2))
```

I'd like to calculate element-wise averages of these two lists which results a list of

```
tibble::lst((A_1$a + A_2$a)/2, (A_1$b + A_2$b)/2)
```

I used

```
purrr::pmap(list(A_1 , A_2), mean)
```

but got

```
Error in mean.default(.l[[1L]][[i]], .l[[2L]][[i]], ...) : 
  'trim' must be numeric of length one`
```

or

```
purrr::map2(A_1, A_2, mean)

Error in mean.default(.x[[i]], .y[[i]], ...) : 
  'trim' must be numeric of length one`
```

Comment: What is `lst`, `pmap`, `map2`? Some package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, We could use:

```
A <-list(A_1, A_2)
lapply(Reduce(\(x, y)Map('+', x, y), A), '/', length(A))

$a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  5.5  7.5  9.5 11.5
[2,]  6.5  8.5 10.5 12.5

$b
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  3.5  5.5  7.5  9.5
[2,]  4.5  6.5  8.5 10.5
```

This code is generic in that we can use to find the mean of several lists.
Note that `A_1` and `A_2` must have the same number of matrices, not necessarily 2. Can be 10 etc. Also note that each corresponding matrix has the same dimensions. Example below:

```
B_1 <- list(matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 2), matrix(c(1,3,4,2), 2),
            matrix(c(1:10), 5), matrix(c(1:20), 5))
B_2 <- lapply(B_1, '*', 2) # In this case, its B_1 * 2
B_3 <- lapply(B_2, '*', 3) #
```

Now you could use the code provide above:

```
B <-list(B_1, B_2, B_3)
lapply(Reduce(\(x, y)Map('+', x, y), B), '/', length(B))
```

Comment: Nice, +1, more succinct we could say `Reduce(\(...) Map('+', ...), A)`.

Comment: I assume `Reduce(\(...) Map('+', ...), A)` could work for averaging over more than 2 lists, right? It works for my 2 lists now without me specifying `x, y` in place of `...`

Comment: @hnguyen. The code x, y works for averaging more than 2 lists. I gave  an example with 3lists each containing 4 matrices of different dimensions. I do not see the purpose of ellipsis. Its jist to complicate the code

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in using the second matrix as `trim=` argument of `mean` whcih is the second. You need to `c`oncatenate the matrices. *Example:*

```
mean(1:3, 2:4)
# Error in mean.default(1:3, 2:4) : 'trim' must be numeric of length one

mean(c(1:3, 2:4))
# [1] 2.5
```

As solution you may use `Map`

```
Map(\(x, y) (x + y)/2, A_1, A_2)
# $a
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]  5.5  7.5  9.5 11.5
# [2,]  6.5  8.5 10.5 12.5
# 
# $b
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]  3.5  5.5  7.5  9.5
# [2,]  4.5  6.5  8.5 10.5
```

Or, why not using arrays?

```
AA_1 <- array(unlist(A_1), dim=c(dim(A_1$a), length(A_1)))
AA_2 <- array(unlist(A_2), dim=c(dim(A_2$a), length(A_2)))

(AA_1 + AA_2)/2
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]  5.5  7.5  9.5 11.5
# [2,]  6.5  8.5 10.5 12.5
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]  3.5  5.5  7.5  9.5
# [2,]  4.5  6.5  8.5 10.5
```

Answer (score 0):

in base R:

```
item_names  <- names(A_1)

structure(
    lapply(item_names, function(name){
        0.5 * (A_1[[name]] + A_2[[name]])
        ## or, if you want the scalar mean:
        ## mean(A_1[[name]] + A_2[[name]])
    }),
    names = item_names
)
```

```
#> $a
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]  5.5  7.5  9.5 11.5
#> [2,]  6.5  8.5 10.5 12.5
#> 
#> $b
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]  3.5  5.5  7.5  9.5
#> [2,]  4.5  6.5  8.5 10.5
```